# Python 64bit SciPy installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

**Task** I want to install Scipy on 64bit python.

**Already Done** I have tried following ways:

- Using `pip install numpy/scipy`-- in this case numpy installs well but scipy fails. error: can't find lpack..
- Install Scipy from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/) -- in this it installs well but on importing gives an error not valid win32 application. As its 32bit and python is 64bit
- Use [gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to install scipy. Installation goes well but when importing any sub-module like `import scipy.stats` throws an error: specified module can not be found.

**Reason to move on 64bit Python** I have 40000 data points csv file. On ruining linkage function python throws a memory error. Some posts suggested to move to 64bit can solve the issue.

Comment: With all due respect to the Task Definition, let me comment on [Reason]. There are more important issues than a static `.CSV` size pushing one to move into 64bit arena. My ML/AI processing works smooth on `200.000+ x 100+` ( in float32 ( not because a 32bit O/S ) due to **`numpy`** `.dtype` set this way in the ML/AI module components). Yes, 64bit O/S will give you less worries about some issues, nevertheless **`python` memory management is not forgiving once working with large dataSets/dataStructures**, both in 32bit & the same in 64bit. Travis' **Anaconda, as @rth noted, is tool of choice**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing scientific Python modules from sources on Windows is a bit complex and not very maintainable.

A more reliable solution is to use a scientific python distribution, such as  [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) or [Enthought Canopy](https://store.enthought.com/).

**Edit:** I understand this answer is opinion based, however I am not aware of other simple and open-source way to deploy scientific python modules on Windows. Sure you could install scipy from sources or with pip, however in a wider picture, if you need Numpy, Scipy, IPython and Matplotlib, etc. that's just not a workable solution.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the entire community, developers included, agree with you on that compling from source is not realistic. Anaconda and EPD are great; I do think WinPython works even better if you use Cython, Numba and theano. Python(x,y) used to be good, but they seem to be behind on the 64bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

Another clean solution is to download the wheel file for SciPy(compatiable with your architecture of Python) and use `pip install pythonModule.whl` and it should install SciPy with no problems. I had to do this the other day and I stumbled upon [this website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), which has many Python modules already compiled to binaries. Just another way to do it if you don't want to download Anaconda.

I did this for NumPy, SciPy, and Scikit-Learn.